how to delete a user in an array with postgres sql command
I have an array that is very complicated, at least for me, to manipulate. I created a json array, but since it is formatted, it is difficult for me to delete a user from the array that is the array of deleted users from the function recoverUser with id, and then I would throw these users recovered from the array of deletedusers to the main array of users, the array did not look the way I thought it would. Can anyone help?
the array(example):
[
    "Usuarios Deletados",
    [
        {
            "usuariosdeletados": {
                "id": "36c1617f-0aa1-4d8e-8c4a-8a8944ef40d2",
                "nome": "Leon S. Polux222222",
                "email": "polux22222222@gmail.com",
                "senha": "$2b$12$DhjLmrsVJSYsxTEu/q.TmO5oGAt2/yCJ0psZ1keA04/ECXRx9BQse",
                "idade": 27,
                "país": "Estadunidense2",
                "documentos": [],
                "deleted": true,
                "created_at": "2024-08-14T23:44:40.558Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "usuariosdeletados": {
                "id": "00a1b88a-4977-478c-af07-c7b79aaf50dc",
                "nome": "Leon S. Polux2",
                "email": "polux2@gmail.com",
                "senha": "$2b$12$rbMY8HIB95wAjOirdYsRMeajGVsnjZTl6IawoDm27ocuPY5WCqJMm",
                "idade": 27,
                "país": "Estadunidense2",
                "documentos": [
                    {
                        "Key": "file",
                        "Nome": "README.md",
                        "Tipo": "MD-MARKDOWN",
                        "Conteudo": [
                            "## Getting Started    Welcome to the VS Code Java world. Here is a guideline to help you get started to write Java code in Visual Studio Code.    ## Folder Structure    The workspace contains two folders by default, where:    - `src`: the folder to maintain sources  - `lib`: the folder to maintain dependencies    Meanwhile, the compiled output files will be generated in the `bin` folder by default.    > If you want to customize the folder structure, open `.vscode/settings.json` and update the related settings there.    ## Dependency Management    The `JAVA PROJECTS` view allows you to manage your dependencies. More details can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-dependency#manage-dependencies).  "
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "deleted": true,
                "created_at": "2024-08-14T23:44:33.031Z"
            }
        }
    ]
]

the recoverUser function:
export async function recuperaUsuario(valores) {
  const { id } = valores.pathParameters;
  const cliente = await pool.connect();
  const result = await cliente.query(
    'SELECT "usuariosdeletados" FROM "Deletados"',
  );
  const usuarios = result.rows;
  const sUsuario = usuarios.map((obj) => obj.usuariosdeletados);
  const usuarioRecuperado = sUsuario.find((usuario) => usuario.id === id);
  if (!usuarioRecuperado) {
    cliente.release();
    throw new Error('Usuario nao deletado ou nao existente');
  } else {
    await cliente.query(
      ` the command I need to delete the user from deletedUser array to transfer to main user arrays`,
      [id],
    );

  }
}

the deletedUser array table sql that I used to create this array to store deleted users:
the "usuariosDeletados" is deletedUsers array
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Deletados" (
    usuariosDeletados JSON DEFAULT '[]'::JSON
  );

I have tried other commands but it always either adds another array to this array or gives an error.

someone to help?
